# Regex for human readable time - 5pm, 5.30 pm, 12 noon

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, momentjs

Some of the things i'm trying to parse are:

```
8am, 12.10pm, 5.45pm 
8am, 11.30am
12noon
12 noon
8 am
7 pm.
```

I have the following without catering for noon - but it doesn't capture all the cases above.

```
^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]).[0-5][0-9][a|p]m$
```

Comment: I think this regex parse all the cases above `[\d]{1,2}(\.[\d]{1,2})?\s?(am|pm|noon)`

Comment: You should remove your final paragraph, which makes the question off-topic, and ask instead for help with the regular expression.

Comment: @CaioOliveira: Your effort will also match 9.9 am, 39.9 pm, and 99,99 noon, none of which are valid times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation should be done outside of regex, as it is not based on semantic, but rather on our understand of time. *While we could do that within the regex, but it will make the pattern really messy.*

The basic form of the pattern should be like this, simple and straight-forward:

```
\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})? ?([a|p]m|noon)
```

But, we will have to add some named groups to isolate different parts of time:

1. Hours: `(?<hours>\d{1,2})`
2. Minutes: `(?<minutes>\d{1,2})`
3. Period: `(?<period>[ap]m|noon)`

Combining all togather: `@"(?<hours>\d{1,2})(\.(?<minutes>\d{1,2}))? ?(?<period>[ap]m|noon)"`

---

The following code captures all part of the string that looks like a human readable time, *just those that is found in your examples*, and parse it into a `TimeSpan` object:

```
var times = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<hours>\d{1,2})(\.(?<minutes>\d{1,2}))? ?(?<period>[ap]m|noon)")
    .Cast<Match>()
    // parse parts of time
    .Select(m => new
    {
        Hours = int.Parse(m.Groups["hours"].Value),
        Minutes = m.Groups["minutes"].Success ? int.Parse(m.Groups["minutes"].Value) : 0,
        IsAfternoon = Regex.IsMatch(m.Groups["period"].Value, "pm|noon"),
    })
    // filter out invalid time
    .Where(x => x.Hours <= 12 && x.Minutes <= 59)
    // convert
    .Select(x => new TimeSpan((x.Hours + (x.IsAfternoon ? 12 : 0)) % 24, x.Minutes, 0));
```

---

EDIT: We have a weird way to write down time: 1pm = 13:00, 2pm = 14:00, ... 11pm = 23:00, 12pm != 24:00 (but = 12:00). And, the above example fails to take that into consideration.

So here a fix:

```
var input = @" Monday 8am, 12.10pm, 5.45pm, 14:24||8:0|0:10|17:45";
var results = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<hours>\d{1,2})([\.:](?<minutes>\d{2}))?(?<period>[ap]m|noon)?")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Where(m => m.Groups["minutes"].Success || m.Groups["period"].Success)
    .Select(m => new
    {
        Hours = int.Parse(m.Groups["hours"].Value),
        Minutes = m.Groups["minutes"].Success ? int.Parse(m.Groups["minutes"].Value) : 0,
        IsAfternoon = m.Groups["period"].Success ? Regex.IsMatch(m.Groups["period"].Value, "pm|noon") : (bool?)null
    })
    .Dump()
    .Where(x => (x.IsAfternoon != null ? x.Hours <= 12 : x.Hours < 24) && x.Minutes <= 59)
    .Select(x => new TimeSpan(
        x.Hours == 12 && x.IsAfternoon == true
            ? 12 
            : x.Hours + (x.IsAfternoon == true ? 12 : 0),
        x.Minutes,
        0));
```

Results:

> 08:00:00
>   12:10:00
>   17:45:00
>   14:24:00
>   00:10:00
>   17:45:00

Comment: This is actually just what I was after - I didn't know how to integrate Regex with the C# parsing. It still doesn't parse  the following correctly - the 12.10pm in particular just parses as 00:10. Besides that it's working fine. 
Monday 8am, 12.10pm, 5.45pm||8:0|0:10|17:45

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use momentjs as you stated in the original question you can:

- customize your locale to parse 'noon' like pm
- use moment parsing with multiple formats

You can use `moment.updateLocale` specifying `meridiemParse` and `isPM` as described in the [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/am-pm-parsing/).

Then you can use [moment parsing with multiple format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/) specifying every format you need (`['ha', 'h a', 'h.mma']` in your example).

Here a working example for the input given in the question:

```js
moment.updateLocale('en', {
  meridiemParse : /[ap]\.?m?\.?|noon/i,
  isPM : function (input) {
    input = (input + '').toLowerCase();
    return input[0] === 'p' || input === 'noon';
  }
});

var arr = ['8am', '12.10pm', '5.45pm', '11.30am', '12noon', '12 noon', '8 am', '7 pm.'];

for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  var m = moment(arr[i], ['ha', 'h a', 'h.mma'], true);
  console.log(m.format('HH:mm'), arr[i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this does it all :) It's a slight modification of your own attempt.

```
(?<![\d.])                              # Mustn't be preceeded by a digit or .
    (?:
        12\s*noon                       # just 12 noon
    |    
        (?:[0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-2])         # 12 hour clock
        (?:\.[0-5][0-9])?               # optional minutes
        \s*(?:[ap]m)                    # mandatory am/pm
    |
        (?:[0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])  # 24 hour clock
        (?:\.[0-5][0-9])?               # optional minutes
    )
(?![\d.]|[ap]m)                         # Correct ending
```

[Check it out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/7MSIUG/3).

PS. You have tagged it as `c#` therefore I assume look-behinds are OK. (there's also the `momentjs` tag which makes me uncertain.)

Comment: Thanks - the momentjs tag was to see if there was a way to use a moment library to parse the human readable time.

Answer (score 0):

```
(1[0-2]|[0-9])(\.[0-5]?[0-9])?\s?([a|p]m|noon)
```

Proof: https://regex101.com/r/9yu6l6/2

Edit: reworked based on edge cases

Comment: Your regex also matches 9.9 am, 39,9 pm, 99.99 noon and 59.6 pm, none of which are valid time values.

Comment: Your edited regex still matches 9.99 am (matches on 9 am), 90.66 noon (matches on 6 noon), 0.7 am (matches entire string), and other invalid times.

Comment: thanks - I'll give this a try and let you know how I go - The input data is assumed to be right, i'm using the reges to know how many occurences of time are in the sentence and to extract them into a timespan object.

Comment: @KenWhite wrapping the string with carat and dollarsign will take away these occurences when testing on a case-by-case. They were not added so that the example can be tested across every line of the input block, which subsequently will allow for matches like 9.99am on the 9am portion.